# tomcat is showing org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, hibernate, tomcat

In my work due to some error in hibernate i rearrange the jar files of lib but after this the project is not getting deployed on tomcat eclipse and showing error 
Caused by:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more

BUT in other application it is working properly
so please help me to to cope up with this problem

> Feb 17, 2016 10:04:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
>   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/Java/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Java/jre8/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
>   Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows
>   Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Xilinx\bin\nt;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Rational\common;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\eclipse;;. Feb 17, 2016 10:04:01 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DoorToDoor' did not
>   find a matching property. Feb 17, 2016 10:04:01 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"] Feb 17, 2016 10:04:01 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Feb 17, 2016 10:04:01 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 774 ms Feb 17, 2016 10:04:01 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Feb 17, 2016 10:04:01 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 Feb 17, 2016 10:04:02 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DoorToDoor]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DoorToDoor]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   HttpServletRequest    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:879)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   HttpServletRequest    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     ... 20 more
>
> Feb 17, 2016 10:04:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Feb 17, 2016 10:04:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more
>
> Feb 17, 2016 10:04:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>   INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"] Feb 17, 2016 10:04:02
>   AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Feb 17, 2016 10:04:02 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
>   service Catalina Feb 17, 2016 10:04:02 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"] Feb 17, 2016 10:04:02 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Yes i have added

Comment: try this.. [this]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823326/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-a-child-container-failed-during-start)

[this one too] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373077/tomcat-7-severe-a-child-container-failed-during-start)

Comment: your tomcat also generate some more stack trace.. Please review your console and put the complete stacktrace console output here..
there are so many reasons may cause for this error..

Comment: yes i Have added... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please read this carefully.. and then check your environment setup you do.

**environments was not found on the java.library.path**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;`  Read this carefully and check is there any JAVA_Home is in your environment variable or not?

You are passing only jre path but if you are actually develop the code you must have install JDK and environment variable should refers to that..

and refer [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)

Comment: sir actually my other projects are running properly with this path..... i have tried upper solution  but not working

Comment: you should add a JAVA_Home or JRE_HOme environment variable and then try to restart your server. If any problem occurs then invoke me.. I think problem with your path I think..

Comment: ok sir i done this as you mentioned,,,  but that path problem remain same,,,   and i tried the other project which is deployed and running properly with the same path not found line.....

Answer (score 1):

**Looks that jars are corrupted.**

To solve it just follow the below steps :

1. Close the servers and IDE.
2. Delete .m2 folder.
3. Delete target folder of your project src.
4. Open IDE and rebuild your project.
5. your server will run now, congrats!